# How to automatically plot a horizontal line for yesterday's 2pm "close"?

Tags: thinkscript

Here is the code I have:

```
input aggregationPeriod = AggregationPeriod.DAY;
input displace = -1;

def is2pmBar = SecondsFromTime(1400) >= 0 and SecondsFromTime(1500) < aggregationPeriod;
def yesterday2pmClose = if is2pmBar then close(period = aggregationPeriod)[-displace] else double.nan;

plot Yesterday2pmCloseValue = yesterday2pmClose;
Yesterday2pmCloseValue.SetDefaultColor(color.new(color.MAGENTA, 1));
Yesterday2pmCloseValue.SetPaintingStrategy(PaintingStrategy.HORIZONTAL);
```

This code is entirely wrong. I have researched it, but I am still unsure how to write it so that it works. I am looking to automatically plot a horizontal line for yesterday's 2pm "close"?

Would appreciate the help. Thanks